# Obfuscate or Encrypt LWC Source Code

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, encryption

I am facing some problems with data injection in LWC where a user is able to set breakpoints in the javascript and change values to get data that they don't have access to. Changes are being made to stop this from the Apex side, but I was wondering if there were any tools or npm packages that could be used to obfuscate or encrypt the javascript in LWC. Normal obfuscaters will not work because of the decorators used in LWC. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure how you plan to obfuscate the LWC code since the code sent to the client is generated by the Salesforce LWC compiler and served direct from the org without you able to get in between the browser and the org.

Comment: It seems clear to me that you simply need to ensure that the client (i.e. the LWC) never receives data that it shouldn't make available to the user - without doing this you would never pass a Salesforce Security Review, for example.

Comment: That seems like the answer to me, @PhilW. All security enforcement should be done in server-side Apex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't get into the compilation and delivery phases for LWC and therefore cannot apply your own obfuscation.

It seems clear to me that you simply need to ensure that the client code (i.e. the LWC) never receives data that it shouldn't make available to the user by enforcing security concerns in your Apex - without doing this you would never pass a Salesforce Security Review, for example.